# Laravel Vue SPA project insecure middlewares localstorage

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication, vue-router, middleware

I'm trying to create an SPA with auth and roles. 
I've been reading a lot of tutorials that explains how to do it and everyone tells the same strategy:

Save the permissions on localstorage, for example accessToken and is_admin=0|1.
So when you login the backend response fills this data.

Then the vue routing is just checking these 2 fields for granting or preventing the access.

This is so unsecure, anyone can access to develop tools and see this data and change it, just writing a random accessToken grants access on this site... and then is_admin = 1 and wala.

Okay, is difficult to KNOW this but... And every single API call checks this accessToken on the backend.

So there is something we can do to prevent this? Or if we want this "agility navigation" we can't protect 100% route navigation middleware?

One of the guides I followed:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/vue-authentication-and-route-handling-using-vue-router

On the questions section so many people is comenting this, and their response is that is a frontend demo... but how can I rely this on the backend? If I want this every navigation click will refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

A SPA will only load once. After that navigation is handled by the frontend. However the data needed for the next page is loaded using ajax from the backend. Meaning you can still validate access in the backend before exposing the data you want to protect.

Comment: So what I understand is a hustler user could access into admin panel but he won't retrieve any data... He only could see static text/images/etc. In addition, when the app would try to retrieve the data, the response with 401 error could do a force redirect.